# Snakemake version mismatch of python, pandas, and numpy

Tags: conda, snakemake

### Original question:

As far as I understand the best practice for snakemake conda envs (see e.g., [this answer and the comment by Johannes Köster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594513/4184258)), each rule should have its own env yaml file to stay modular and maintainable. In my case that's ~25 environments. Typically, these should only specify the minimally needed tools for each rule, I think.

However, that fails for some of the rules, where the tools installed within the rule env pull versions of `pandas` or `numpy` that are not identical to the versions in the "parent" env in which snakemak is being run.

For example, a `pandas` mismatch results in

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals'
```

And with `numpy` I get

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:
```

Both are easy to solve by specifying the same versions of `pandas` and `numpy` as the parent environment. Say, the conda env that runs snakemake has these dependencies:

```
  - python ==3.7.10
  - pandas ==1.3.1
  - numpy ==1.21.0
```

Then, adding these three lines to all my individual rule.yaml files solves the above problems.

However, this does not seem like a good or even correct solution to me. With this, any update of the version of either of these dependencies requires me to change it in all rule yaml files.

As far as I understand, this stems from conda's default to deactivate an env before activating another, instead of stacking/nesting them (see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation)).

Is there:

- A way to activate rule envs by stacking/nesting them within the main env from which snakemake is being run (I don't want to set the global `auto_stack` of conda, as this might interfere with other stuff)?
- Or a way to refer to or 'include' a general yaml files into each rule file, so that the three dependencies do not have to be listed in each of them?
- Another solution that I am not seeing?

**Edit:** It seems that at least the numpy error is an incredibly convoluted bug in snakemake. I have [submitted this as an issue to snakemake now](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1640). Still, the general question remains of how to avoid duplication of environment specifications.

### Update:

Since asking the question originally, I have played around with it a bit more, see [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1640#issuecomment-1124420898), which also contains a minimal example to test this.

The issue boils down to this:

- Snakemake stacks (nests) environments when calling a rule that has a `conda` environment specification. My initial guess above was hence wrong.
- When this environment has a version of python/numpy/pandas that conflicts with the parent env in which Snakemake is run, we can easily get errors (as shown above).
- This for example happens when a tool requested in that env has a (implicit) dependency on python/pandas, and conda pulls in a conflicting version.
- To prevent this, we can of course explicitly request non-conflicting versions of python in the env, but that seems wasteful and harder to maintain.

Are there better solutions to this?

Comment: Could you please share the source of the information about the stacking of the conda environments in Snakemake? Or did you just figure it out by yourself?

Comment: @OliverKüchler, see the link to the Snakemake [GitHub issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1640#issuecomment-1124420898) that I posted with the "Update" above. It explains the steps that I took to figure out that Snakemake stacks/nests environments. Is that what you are looking for? I don't have another source - just the experiments as explained there. If you have more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand the best practice for snakemake conda envs, each rule should have its own env yaml file to stay modular and maintainable.

Do you have a reference for this? As you say, that means creating lots of environments. Besides, running `conda activate` before every execution of every rule is going to increase the running time quite a bit.

I usually create a conda environment for the entire project, *i.e.* for the whole snakemake pipeline, and create rule-specific environments in case of incompatibilities (e.g. the rule needs python2).

Comment: Yes, for the reference see [this answer and the comment by Johannes Köster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594513/4184258). In short: It's more modular, maintainable, and wrappers do it anyway that way. 

As for one environment for the entire project (except for wrappers): Yes, I do have conflicts, hence individual envs are needed for some rules anyway. But in particular your example of "rule needs python2" is part of my problem: In some cases, if python/pandas/numpy versions don't match, I get in trouble.

Comment: Further reference for using fine-grained environments: [official documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v7.6.2/snakefiles/deployment.html), saying "make sure to keep them as finegrained as possible to improve transparency and maintainability".

Comment: Regarding managing environments, I would be happy to see a bigger discussion around it. The example in the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v7.6.2/snakefiles/deployment.html), if informative, has two modules (modulel1.smk, module2.smk) and two envs. I would imagine each module accomplishes a self-contained task and has more than one rule in it. So the envs are not really fine-grained to the individual rules...?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have more recommendations and best practices around this. It is unclear to me for example whether it's recommended to (1) run Snakemake in an environment `snakemake-7.6.1`, and have rules request an environment containing the needed tools (could be the same env for all rules, or different ones), or (2) run Snakemake in an environment `my-pipeline-env` that already contains all tools (maybe except the conflicting ones), and then using conda minimally (only to resolve conflicts) within the rules.