# Pytorch, Pandas, Numpy different result on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, conda

We are working on an AI project which amongst others calculates the position of a human body lying in a bed. External supporters provided us a code package which does this job and calculates the deviation between the real position of the body (detected by a camera) and the predicted position.

That code package has been developed on Windows and now needs to be ported to Ubuntu 20.04. Until now, in the code package for Ubuntu, we just changed some path names (backslash to slash) to make it work.

If we now run – the exactly same - code with the exactly same training and test data under Windows 10 and Ubuntu we observe the following strange behaviour:

The deviation between real body positions and predicted body positions is 25mm (average value) in Windows, which is a good result for our purposes and excepted as a match. In Ubuntu the deviation is 150mm (average value), which is a not usable result.

We also ran the Windows code package in a Windows 10 VM (Virtualbox) on the respective Ubuntu machine. The result is close to the result we get when running the code under ‘plain‘ Ubuntu (not usable).

When running under Ubuntu, there is no difference whether we utilize CPU or GPU.

The code is written in Python 3 and executed under Python 3.7.12 in an Anaconda 3 virtual environment.

We assume that Linux/Ubuntu does not fully support a certain CPU instruction set. but at the end we do not have an explanation for this behaviour. Does anybody have an idea?

Our CPU:

Intel Core I7 (Caby Lake)

Our env.yaml for conda:

```
name: cosy-bunk-3.7
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - ipykernel
  - torchvision
  - pytorch
  - cudatoolkit=10.2
  - torchaudio
  - plotly
  - scikit-learn
  - pip
  - pip:
    - optuna
    - dash
```

Output of 'conda list‘ under Ubuntu:

```
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
alembic                   1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
alsa-lib                  1.2.6.1              h7f98852_0    conda-forge
attr                      2.5.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
attrs                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
autopage                  0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.1                    openblas    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h540881e_1004    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            ha878542_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15        py37h89c1867_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py37h43b0acd_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cliff                     3.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
cmaes                     0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cmd2                      2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colorlog                  6.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              37.0.4           py37h38fbfac_0    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.2.89             h713d32c_10    conda-forge
cudnn                     7.6.5.32             h01f27c4_1    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dash                      2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-core-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-html-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-table                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.6               h5008d03_3    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.0            py37hd23a5d3_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.8                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
fftw                      3.3.10          nompi_ha7695d1_103    conda-forge
flask                     2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-compress            1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.0               h8e229c2_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.34.4           py37h540881e_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h73d1719_1008    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h36c2ea0_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
greenlet                  1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
gst-plugins-base          1.20.3               hf6a322e_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.20.3               hd4edc92_0    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.15.1             pyh210e3f2_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.33.0           py37h89c1867_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jack                      1.9.18            h8c3723f_1002    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.11.1           py37h89c1867_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py37h7cecad7_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               h3790be6_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 hddcbb42_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.36.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           15_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h166bdaf_7    conda-forge
libcap                    2.64                 ha37c62d_0    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           15_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  14.0.6          default_h2e3cab8_0    conda-forge
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h3a83d3e_0    conda-forge
libcups                   2.3.3                hf5a7f15_1    conda-forge
libdb                     6.2.32               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.13                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libflac                   1.3.4                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.1.0              h69a702a_16    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.1.0              hdcd56e2_16    conda-forge
libglib                   2.72.1               h2d90d5f_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           15_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm14                 14.0.6               he0ac6c6_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.20          pthreads_h78a6416_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h753d276_3    conda-forge
libpq                     14.4                 hd77ab85_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.20.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
libsndfile                1.0.31               h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.1.0              ha89aaad_16    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                h0e0dad5_3    conda-forge
libtool                   2.4.6             h9c3ff4c_1008    conda-forge
libudev1                  249                  h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.3                h522a892_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.3                h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.14               h22db469_3    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               14.0.4               he0ac6c6_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
magma                     2.5.4                h5da55e3_2    conda-forge
mako                      1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.2            py37h89c1867_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py37hc347a89_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.1.0           h84fe81f_915    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.30               haf5c9bc_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.30               h28c427c_0    conda-forge
nccl                      2.13.4.1             h1a5f58c_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ninja                     1.11.0               h924138e_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.32                 h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
nss                       3.78                 h2350873_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.6           py37h976b520_0    conda-forge
openblas                  0.3.20          pthreads_h320a7e8_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                hb52868f_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
optuna                    2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.5            py37he8f5f7f_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pbr                       5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0            py37h44f0d7a_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
portaudio                 19.6.0               h57a0ea0_5    conda-forge
prettytable               3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.30             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.1            py37h540881e_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pulseaudio                14.0                 h7f54b18_8    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyperclip                 1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.15.7           py37hf30b843_0    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py37hd23a5d3_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37h89c1867_5    conda-forge
python                    3.7.12          hb7a2778_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.12.0          cuda102py37haad9b4f_202    conda-forge
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2022.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py37h0c0c2a8_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.4               ha5833f6_2    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h0f457ee_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py37hf9e9bfc_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.3            py37hf2a6cf1_0    conda-forge
setuptools                59.8.0           py37h89c1867_1    conda-forge
sip                       6.6.2            py37hd23a5d3_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sleef                     3.5.1                h9b69904_2    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.4.40                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.39.2               h4ff8645_0    conda-forge
stevedore                 3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.5.0             h924138e_1    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torchaudio                0.12.0               py37_cu102    pytorch
torchvision               0.13.0          cuda102py37h9785060_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.2              py37h540881e_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.3.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.3.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py37h540881e_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.11            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xcb-util                  0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-image            0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-keysyms          0.4.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-renderutil       0.3.9                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xcb-util-wm               0.4.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.12               h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h8a70e8d_3    conda-forge
```

Output of 'conda list‘ under Windows:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alembic                   1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
autopage                  0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl    anaconda
brotli                    1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h8ffe710_7    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15        py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py37hd8e9650_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cliff                     3.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
cmaes                     0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cmd2                      2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorlog                  6.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               11.3.1              h280eb24_10    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dash                      2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-core-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-html-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-table                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.6.0            py37hf2a7229_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flask                     2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-compress            1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.34.4           py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h546665d_1    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py37h03978a9_5    conda-forge
greenlet                  1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0  [vc14]  anaconda
importlib-metadata        4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2022.1.0          h57928b3_3787    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.15.1             pyh025b116_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.33.0           py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9b               vc14h4d7706e_1  [vc14]  anaconda
jupyter_client            7.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.11.1           py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py37h8c56517_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h8ffe710_7    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h8ffe710_7    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h8ffe710_7    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h1d00b33_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.39.2               h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.8           vc14h04e2a1e_10  [vc14]  anaconda
libuv                     1.44.2               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.4                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mako                      1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.3            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.3            py37h54234da_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           h0e2418a_729    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0            py37h75fcce0_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ninja                     1.11.0               h2d74725_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.6           py37h2830a78_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
optuna                    2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.5            py37h9386db6_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pbr                       5.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0            py37hdc2b20a_1  
pip                       22.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prettytable               3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.30             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.1            py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyperclip                 1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_4    conda-forge
pyreadline3               3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.12          h7840368_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.10.2          cpu_py37h907fbb5_0    anaconda
pytz                      2022.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   303              py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py37hcce574b_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]  anaconda
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py37hcabfae0_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.3            py37hb6553fb_0    conda-forge
setuptools                59.8.0           py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8          py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.4.40                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.39.2               h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
stevedore                 3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.5.0             h2d74725_1    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.7            vc14hb68737d_1  [vc14]  anaconda
torchaudio                0.10.2               py37_cu113    pytorch
torchvision               0.11.3               py37_cu113    pytorch
tornado                   6.2              py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.3.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.3.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_6    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.29.30037          h902a5da_6    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
```

Comment: `pytorch` has different versions `1.10` and `1.12`. Should probably try to have it be equal What happens when you train your model on windows, export it and load it under ubuntu. Then run the model on the same test data and compare outputs. Are they the same? Are you using seed values for the random initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deeper research we discovered the error in the prepairing of the data caused by the different handling of os.listdir() in python. The order is not the same on windows and linux machines.

Comment: I’m still confused why the Windows VM run was similar to the Ubuntu run. Shouldn’t that have had paths similar to the native Windows run?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more consistency in your environment solves, then add specificity to your YAML. I would recommend specifying every package that is important to you **up through minor version**. That is [what is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594513/570918) for Conda YAMLs amongst the Snakemake community.

Also, the channel order doesn't make sense, and is potentially a source of inconsistency. If using PyTorch, then the `pytorch` channel should absolutely be top priority. Also, `anaconda` is a subset of `defaults`, so that's unnecessary. I'd change the channels to:

```yaml
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
  - nodefaults
```

And the `nodefaults` at the end is a directive to ignore any system- or user-level configured channels, ensuring only the YAML channels are considered.

Comment: Isn't `anaconda` a mirror of the default `main` channel?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes, [that's what is documented](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-repositories/). `anaconda` is the same as `main`, and `defaults` includes `main`, `r`, and (on windows) `msys2`. So, maybe if one doesn't want `r` channel, then use `anaconda` instead of `defaults`, but don't use both.

Answer (score -3):

I guess there is some version issues in the conda env. When you use python 3 the conda env manages all the compatible packages to your env. So when you use python 3.7 the packages are updated. You will have different versions for each package . i can suggest you can either use pip or docker containers.

Comment: The environment is both times created with python=3.7, don't get what you mean with `when you use python 3.7 the packages are updated`. It is true that during solving of the environment slightly different versions of packages might be chosen, but that is OS related, not python version related. Using `pip`, this can happen just as easily.

Comment: you have version mismatches . check ubuntu pytorch the version is 1.12.0  and  windows pytorch is 1.10.2.