# Cannot use snakemake containerize flag when I'm using already existing named environments

Tags: conda, snakemake

Here is what I tried:

`snakemake --use-conda --conda-frontend conda --containerize > dockerfile`

This produces the following error:

```
File "/REDACTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/containerize.py", line 32, in containerize
    envs = sorted(
  File "/REDACTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/containerize.py", line 30, in relfile
    return env.file.get_path_or_uri()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_path_or_uri'
```

Reproducible example is below:

Main snakefile:

```
configfile: "conf/config.yaml"
rule all:
    input:
        "output.txt"
include: "rules/test.smk"
```

test.smk snakefile:

```
rule test:
    output:
        "output.txt"
    conda:
        "biotools"
    shell:
        """
        python -VV > {output}
        """
```

Removing conda subcommand from the above works (obviously). Putting a file `py38.yaml` in `env` directory in `rules` folder and replacing `conda:"biotools"` with `conda:"envs/py38.yaml"` works.
But I specifically want my container to include already named conda environments.

Do I really have to rewrite my workflow to replace all instances of `conda:X` with `conda:envs/X.yaml` and plop all my conda environs into `.yaml` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it only works with YAML definitions. [Consider filing a feature request](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues).

A simple solution is to dump out YAMLs for your environment:

```
## minimal version
mamba env export -n biotools > biotools.min.yaml

## full version
mamba env export -n biotools > biotools.full.yaml
```

then use one of those instead. There are some recommendations [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594513/570918) on best practice for YAML constraints, i.e., you may want to adjust the YAML to be more transportable.

Note that it is generally discouraged to use named environments in Snakemake pipelines because they undermine reproducibility.